# How to connect a third party system to Gitlab for authentication

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I want to connect my own system to gitlab only for authentication.

After that i should be able to manage all the usernames and passwords of gitlab through my system.

Could you please help me to solve this scenario. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That would be using the [GitLab User API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html) (as admin of your GitLab instance)

You can then [add SSH keys for a user](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#add-ssh-key-for-user), or [modify an existing user account](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#user-modification) (including their password)

You can do so through any number of [GitLab API client](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#user-modification).

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. Actually I want to change the Gitlab Password from my own system through API calls. I tried it through below PUT request.

Comment: http://<ip>:<port>/api/v4/users/29/?private_token=<private_token>       body->{
 "password":"1qaz2wsx"
}

Comment: but once I change the password in the next login it redirects to the re-set password page. Thats the issue I am trying to solve. Do you have any idea for that. I search about this a lot. But every one have the same issue. Not solved yet